# Custom Sort using Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

Consider the dto class below -

```
public class RoleDto {

  private String name;

  RoleDto(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Its instances would contain names like -

```
Business Practitioner - Expert
Developer - Expert
Developer - Master
Business Practitioner - Master
Business Practitioner
Developer
Developer - Professional
Business Practitioner - Professional
```

I want to sort the instances such that the order is -

```
Business Practitioner - Expert
Business Practitioner - Master
Business Practitioner - Professional
Business Practitioner

Developer - Expert
Developer - Master
Developer - Professional
Developer
```

I have used the code below -

```
ArrayList<RoleDto> roles = new ArrayList<>();
roles.add(new RoleDto("Business Practitioner - Expert"));
roles.add(new RoleDto("Developer - Expert"));
roles.add(new RoleDto("Developer - Master"));
roles.add(new RoleDto("Business Practitioner - Master"));
roles.add(new RoleDto("Business Practitioner"));
roles.add(new RoleDto("Developer"));
roles.add(new RoleDto("Developer - Professional"));
roles.add(new RoleDto("Business Practitioner - Professional"));

List<RoleDto> sorted = roles.stream().sorted(comparing(r -> r.getName(),
    comparing((String s) -> !s.contains("-")))).collect(toList());

for(RoleDto r : sorted)
System.out.println(r.getName());
```

However the output is

```
Business Practitioner - Expert
Developer - Expert
Developer - Master
Business Practitioner - Master
Developer - Professional
Business Practitioner - Professional
Business Practitioner
Developer
```

Can someone please help me achieve the expected result

Comment: `!s.contains("-")` return `boolean`, method `compare` of the `Comparator` interface returns an `int`. you have to provide an implementation of this method or make use of the static method defined in the `Comparator` interface to create an instance of `Comparator`.

Comment: Are all the possible values known at compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest changing your RoleDto to have two attributes: String role and String level

Now the code for sorting List would look like:

```
Comparator<RoleDto> compareByRoleAndLevel = Comparator
                    .comparing(RoleDto::getRole)
                    .thenComparing(RoleDto::getLevel);
 
List<RoleDto> sortedRoles = roles.stream()
                .sorted(compareByRoleAndLevel)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, @Orr - Adding role and level makes more sense. But the above sorting logic produces puts "Developer" and "Business Practitioner" at the top of their respective groups. I  need to put it at the bottom of their group?

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired result after adding roles and level and changing the code to below

Comment: roles.stream().sorted(comparing(RoleDto::getRole).thenComparing(RoleDto::getLevel, Comparator.nullsLast(naturalOrder()))).collect(toList()));

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually compare the names, the compare just checks whether or not the names contain "-", which is why you are getting all that do (in random order) before all that don't (in random order). If you can change the Dto, see the answer of @Orr, otherwise you could do the name split/compare in place, like this:

```
    final List<RoleDto> sorted =
        roles.stream()
            .sorted(
                comparing(
                    RoleDto::getName,
                    comparing((String s) -> s.split(" - ")[0])
                        .reversed()
                        .thenComparing(s -> s.split(" - ").length)
                        .reversed()
                        .thenComparing(s -> s.split(" - ")[1])))
            .collect(toList());
```

The reversing may seem a little unintuitive, but effectively every reverse reverses all the previous comparisons, so the first comparison get reversed twice. To skip that, you could instead write:

```
    final List<RoleDto> sorted =
        roles.stream()
            .sorted(
                comparing(
                    RoleDto::getName,
                    comparing((String s) -> s.split(" - ")[0])
                        .thenComparing(s -> -s.split(" - ").length)
                        .thenComparing(s -> s.split(" - ")[1])))
            .collect(toList());
```

(notice the minus sign in the middle compare)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have two dimensions of data at play here.

- **Business function**
  "Business Practitioner" & "Programmer".
- **Level of proficiency**
  "Expert", "Master", "Professional", and implicitly "Standard", "Basic", "Novice", or some such (shown as no text).

Trying to represent such values as text is clumsy, and ignores the features built into Java for such a purpose.

If all the values are known at compile-time, make an enum for each dimension. An enum is a class defined in such a way as to automatically instantiate and name several objects when the class is loaded.

```
public enum Function { BUSINESS_PRACTITIONER, PROGRAMMER ; }
public enum Proficiency { EXPERT, MASTER, PROFESSIONAL, NOVICE; }
```

Pull those together into a single class. The primary purpose of this class is to carry data transparently and immutably. So we can define briefly as a [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
public record Role( Function function , Proficiency proficiency ) { }
```

We want instances of `Role` to sort in two levels, first by `Function`, then by `Proficiency`. So we need to implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface on our record `Role`.

```
public record Role( Function function , Proficiency proficiency ) implements Comparable<Role> { … }
```

The sort order of each is the order in which the named objects are declared. So we can write the necessary [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method using a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) object. We define that `Comparator` object using convenience methods `comparing` and `thenComparing`, passing each a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). We mark this object as a singleton using `static`, for frequent re-use.

```
private static Comparator < Role > comparator =
        Comparator
                .comparing( Role :: function )
                .thenComparing( Role :: proficiency );
```

We use that comparator in our `compareTo` method.

```
@Override public int compareTo ( Role other ) { return Role.comparator.compare( this , other ); }
```

We instantiate a role object like this:

```
Role progPro = new Role( Function.PROGRAMMER , Proficiency.PROFESSIONAL );
```

If need be, we can make a set of all possible roles.

```java
NavigableSet < Role > allPossibleRoles = new TreeSet();
for ( Function function : Function.values() )
{
    for ( Proficiency proficiency : Proficiency.values() )
    {
        allPossibleRoles.add( new Role( function , proficiency ) );
    }
}
System.out.println( "allPossibleRoles = " + allPossibleRoles );
```

We can see these are listed in the order dictated by the Question.

> allPossibleRoles = [Role[function=BUSINESS_PRACTITIONER, proficiency=EXPERT], Role[function=BUSINESS_PRACTITIONER, proficiency=MASTER], Role[function=BUSINESS_PRACTITIONER, proficiency=PROFESSIONAL], Role[function=BUSINESS_PRACTITIONER, proficiency=NOVICE], Role[function=PROGRAMMER, proficiency=EXPERT], Role[function=PROGRAMMER, proficiency=MASTER], Role[function=PROGRAMMER, proficiency=PROFESSIONAL], Role[function=PROGRAMMER, proficiency=NOVICE]]

Lastly, we need to emit the text seen in the Question.

Modify the enum classes to take an argument for a display name.

```java
public enum Function
{
    BUSINESS_PRACTITIONER( "Business Practitioner" ), PROGRAMMER( "Programmer" );

    private final String displayName;

    // Constructor
    Function ( final String displayName ) { this.displayName = displayName; }

    public String getDisplayName ( ) { return displayName; }
}
```

And the other enum.

```java
public enum Proficiency
{
    EXPERT( "Expert" ), MASTER( "Master" ), PROFESSIONAL( "Professional" ), NOVICE( "" );

    private final String displayName;

    // Constructor
    Proficiency ( String displayName ) { this.displayName = displayName; }

    public String getDisplayName ( ) { return displayName; }
}
```

Modify the `Role` record to generate text in desired format with a `getDisplayName` method.

```java
import java.util.Comparator;

public record Role( Function function , Proficiency proficiency ) implements Comparable < Role >
{
    @Override
    public int compareTo ( Role other ) { return Role.comparator.compare( this , other ); }

    private static Comparator < Role > comparator =
            Comparator
                    .comparing( Role :: function )
                    .thenComparing( Role :: proficiency );

    public String getDisplayName ( )
    {
        String x = this.function.getDisplayName();
        String y = this.proficiency.getDisplayName().isBlank() ? "" : " - ";
        String z = this.proficiency.getDisplayName();
        return x + y + z;
    }
}
```

Example usage.

```java
NavigableSet < Role > allPossibleRoles = new TreeSet();  // NavigableSet/TreeSet keeps elements sorted.
for ( Function function : Function.values() )
{
    for ( Proficiency proficiency : Proficiency.values() )
    {
        allPossibleRoles.add( new Role( function , proficiency ) );
    }
}

// Dump to console.
for ( Role role : allPossibleRoles )
{
    System.out.println( "role.getDisplayName() = " + role.getDisplayName() );
}
```

```
role.getDisplayName() = Business Practitioner - Expert
role.getDisplayName() = Business Practitioner - Master
role.getDisplayName() = Business Practitioner - Professional
role.getDisplayName() = Business Practitioner
role.getDisplayName() = Programmer - Expert
role.getDisplayName() = Programmer - Master
role.getDisplayName() = Programmer - Professional
role.getDisplayName() = Programmer
```